# I made new local git repository but it show this message. fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'

Tags: git, head, revision, git-init

Hi I just made a new git local repository in my local machine.

```
Jon-linux ∴ mkdir git_test

Jon-linux ∴ cd git_test 

Jon-linux ∴ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/jonghyeon/git_test/.git/
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
```

I want to remove that fatal message, so I googled it and I found some, however, it doesn't work for me.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does your shell have Git integration?  If so, which one and what version?

Comment: Additionally to @bk2204 comment, what shell are you using? I can only tell that this is fairly rare or a customized shell.

Comment: I am using zsh and I customized it. I installed git using sudo apt-get install git-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to remove that fatal message,

Simply add some files (`git add .`) and `git commit -m "my first commit"`

The error message (probably triggered by your zsh prompt) will go away.

Comment: @JonghyeonJeon What does `git status` return when done inside your Git repository folder?

Comment: @JonghyeonJeon What changed? How the issue is now solved?